# Acknowledgement option Client mode in JMS

Tags: jms

I am trying to understand the Acknowledgement option Client mode in JMS.
in this mode , does the consumer actually have to send an Acknowledgement message back to the queue ? and if so what should be in the message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, consumer application does not send any message back to queue. In Client Acknowledgement mode, after a message is received, client application has to call `Acknowledge()` method of the received message object. This method call will ensure the message is removed from the provider.

Comment: What happens with message if we don't call this method?

Comment: The message doesn't get removed from the queue and can be redelivered to application.